# How to find filenames longer than 42 chars on Mac OS

Tags: macos, shell, automator

I need to shorten the names of some files on an external hard drive in order to store them on another encrypted drive (The encryption doesn't allow filenames to be longer than 42 chars). The files I need to rename are organized in multiple folders with arbitrary sub-folder depth.

I'm thinking about two options to do this:

- Is there some way to get a list of the files with a filename longer than 42 chars in Automator? I'd then rename them by hand - I don't expect them to be much.
- Is there a simple but robust shell script which crops filenames to a specific length (iteratively for all folders and recursively for all subfolders)? It should possibly also be able to handle conflicts if the cropping of multiple filenames leads to the same filename.

Can you help me with some of the options? Or do you have any other options to suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in the shell... `find` will give you a list of all files recursing down into the subdirectories, starting at `dot` - the current directory:

```
find .
```

**Output**

```
./vips/libvips/tools/vipsedit.c
./vips/libvips/tools/vipsheader.c
./vips/libvips/tools/vipsprofile
./vips/libvips/tools/vipsthumbnail.c
./vips/libvips/vips-cpp.pc.in
./vips/libvips/vips.pc.in
./vips/libvips/vipsCC.pc.in
```

then `awk` can tell you the lengths:

```
find . | awk '{l=length($0);print length,$0}'
```

**Output**

```
33 ./vips/libvips/tools/vipsheader.c
32 ./vips/libvips/tools/vipsprofile
36 ./vips/libvips/tools/vipsthumbnail.c
29 ./vips/libvips/vips-cpp.pc.in
25 ./vips/libvips/vips.pc.in
27 ./vips/libvips/vipsCC.pc.in
```

Or, if you only want the ones longer than 32:

```
find . | awk '{l=length($0);if(length>32)print length,$0}'
```

**Output**

```
43 ./vips/libvips/tools/batch_image_convert.in
42 ./vips/libvips/tools/batch_rubber_sheet.in
37 ./vips/libvips/tools/light_correct.in
36 ./vips/libvips/tools/shrink_width.in
33 ./vips/libvips/tools/vipsheader.c
36 ./vips/libvips/tools/vipsthumbnail.c
```

Or you can use this:

```
find . | awk '{base=$0;sub(/.*\//,"",base);x=length(base);if(x>42)print $0,x,base}'
```

The `awk` gets the whole line in $0, then copies it to `base`. It then strips off everything up to the last slash and resaves that as `base`. Then it gets the length of `base` and, if greater than 42, shows you the full original name, the length of the base name and the basename itself.

Comment: Thanks! That was very useful and detailed!

Answer (score 3):

The `find` tool supports regular expressions which provide an easy way to filter files by length:

```
find -E . -regex '.*/[^/]{43,}'
```

Answer (score 1):

**Assumption**

You just want to use the encrypted drive for back-up and not for day-to-day use.

**Answer**

Create a `zip`/`tar.gz` of the files for storage on the back-up drive.  This will maintain the names, permissions and times of your files.

**EDIT** Assumption didn't work out.

Option #2: Create a virtual filesystem on the encrypted drive. [This answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/101841/options-on-a-mac-for-a-writable-compressed-file-system) on *Ask Different* shows how to use MacZFS for this, however I don't see why you can't simply use HFS+.

Comment: Good thinking - have my vote! By the way, on OSX, you can just right-click on a directory/folder and select `Compress` and it will make the ZIP for you.

Comment: Cheers Mark. I prefer `tar` as it preserves more metadata (symlinks, etc) :)  I don't think there is a perfect solution to the question; if the OP wants to actually use the files on the encrypted drive then this answer has no value.

Comment: This is actually a good idea assuming the use case. It may free me from the copying issue. However, I'd like to access the files from time to time on the encrypted drive. In those situations I'd like to avoid downloading a >40GB file and unzipping it. It's true that I may split the files among multiple folders, which may reduce the size of the individual files - but it's not super convenient for me.